# How can I check a String in Flutter for only line breaks or spaces? (Flutter, Dart)

Tags: string, flutter, dart

I want to check if a `TextInputField` has input containing only line breaks or spaces.

In other words, if the input contains anything other than line breaks or spaces.

How can I do that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe the `trim` method combined with `isEmpty` will be of use here

```
void main() {
  print(checkEmpty(''));                // true
  print(checkEmpty('          '));      // true
  print(checkEmpty('\n\n\n\n'));        // true
  print(checkEmpty('             z'));  // false
  print(checkEmpty('\n\t'));            // true
}

bool checkEmpty(String val) {
  return val.trim().isEmpty;
}
```